# Repeat loop after EOF

Tags: sql, asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, recordset

It is posible to repeat loop again throught recordset after first loop?

```
<%
Response.Writ5 "First Loop"
do while not rs.EOF 
     Response.Write "<option>" & rs.Fields(0) & "</option>" & vbCrLf
   rs.MoveNext 
loop

'repeat
Response.Write "Second Loop"
do while not rs.EOF 
     Response.Write "<option>" & rs.Fields(0) & "</option>" & vbCrLf
   rs.MoveNext 
loop

%>
```

Comment: read the recordset into an array, loop through the array

Comment: Why ask the same question twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: No.

Record sets are forward only collections, there is no "SeekToStart" operation.

if you need to pass over the data twice copy it into a local array, if the quantity of data is too much for that, then you probably need to rethink your approach.